# What are those `edg***.tmp` files created by Visual Studio 2017 in %temp% directory used for?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have redirected the `%temp%` environment variable to my RAMDISK to achieve better system response. However, I  have found that Visual Studio 2017 always creates several `edg***.tmp` files in the folder and each of the files are of size ~ 600MB.  The files are always opened as long as Visual Studio is running. The RAMDISK (4G) soon runs out of space.

I tried to set the location of IntelliSense files, but these files are still there.   What are the files used for and is it possible to move the files somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with vs2017.

It seems these files has something to do with IntelliSense (see https://www.edg.com ).

So perhaps you put fallback location for intellisense on ram disk.

With vs2015 these files are much smaller, but with vs2017 they are much bigger.

So you can:

- not use fallback location on ramdisk
- set Max Cached Translation Units to 2 (minimum possible value)

Comment: Well, for other problems I am not using RAM disks now, so I cannot test your suggestion ... Thanks anyway.